# How do i use templated values as keys in a map?

Tags: c++, templates, maps

Im trying to implement a 3 dimensional matrix using `stl::map`.

I have a map whose "keys" are templated and "values" are other maps(for the other dimension). Here is the compiler error I get-

```
graph.h|37| error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘map’ with no type·
```

So is it true that I cannot have a templated value as a map's keys or is there another way to do it. Here is the part of my code where Im attempting to do so-

```
using namespace std;
template <class V>·
class Graph {
    ...
    map<V, map<V,int> > vertices;·
    ...
};
```

------ UPDATE:

My comment saying I fixed it is being hidden, the mistake is silly, I should have been using `std::map` and not map directly. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you `#include`d `<map>` and are you `using namespace std`?

Comment: Yes, Il update my post to show that. thx

Comment: `using std::map;` would be better than pulling the whole of `std` namespace in, given this is in a header file.

Comment: @sri Also, why are there dots after some lines?

Comment: @quasiverse, those dots are part of my vim UI, which got copied. They shouldn't affect the code.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, that did it.  I am not wording my namespaces nicely. I'l get to cleaning up my code right away. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it true that I cannot have a templated value as a map's keys?

No, There is no such rule. If there was any such rule it would mean power of Generic Programming, the very purpose of existence of Templates would be useless.

> or is there another way to do it?

You are just having an syntax error, because you did not qualify map with its (std)namespace.

Works fine for me **[here](http://ideone.com/6W10A)**

```
#include<map>

template <class V> class Graph 
{
     std::map<V, std::map<V,int> > vertices;

};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```